# C# : Merging Dictionary and List

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a `List` of `String` like

```
List<String> MyList=new List<String>{"A","B"};
```

and a

```
Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String,String>> MyDict=new Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,String>>();
```

which contains

```
 Key      Value
          Key     Value

   "ONE"        "A_1"  "1"
                "A_2"  "2"
                "X_1"  "3"
                "X_2"  "4"
                "B_1"  "5"

    "TWO"       "Y_1"  "1"
                "B_9"  "2"
                "A_4"  "3"
                "B_2"   "6"
                "X_3" "7"
```

I need to merge the the list and Dictionary into a new Dictionary

```
 Dictionary<String,String> ResultDict = new Dictionary<String,String>()
```

The resulting  dictionary contains

```
Key Value

"A_1"   "1"
"A_2"   "2"
"B_1"   "5"
"A_4"   "3"
"B_2"   "6"
"X_2"   "4"
"X_3"   "7"
```

Merge rule

1. First add the items which has a substring equals to any item in the list.
2. Then Merge the items in the "MyDict" so the result should not contain duplicate keys as    well as duplicate values.

Here is my source code.

```
        Dictionary<String, String> ResultDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        List<String> TempList = new List<string>(MyDict.Keys);
        for (int i = 0; i < TempList.Count; i++)
        {
            ResultDict = ResultDict.Concat(MyDict[TempList[i]])
                                              .Where(TEMP => MyList.Contains(TEMP.Key.Contains('_') == true ? TEMP.Key.Substring(0, TEMP.Key.LastIndexOf('_'))
                                                                                                            : TEMP.Key.Trim()))
                                              .ToLookup(TEMP => TEMP.Key, TEMP => TEMP.Value)
                                              .ToDictionary(TEMP => TEMP.Key, TEMP => TEMP.First())
                                              .GroupBy(pair => pair.Value)
                                              .Select(group => group.First())
                                              .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);            }
        for (int i = 0; i < TempList.Count; i++)
        {
            ResultDict = ResultDict.Concat(MyDict[TempList[i]])
                                              .ToLookup(TEMP => TEMP.Key, TEMP => TEMP.Value)
                                              .ToDictionary(TEMP => TEMP.Key, TEMP => TEMP.First())
                                              .GroupBy(pair => pair.Value)
                                              .Select(group => group.First())
                                              .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
        }
```

its working fine, but I need to eliminate the two for loops or at least one
(Any way to do this using LINQ or LAMBDA expression)

Comment: In your example, `MyList` doesn't include `"X"` so why are `"X_2"` and `"X_3"` in the resulting dictionary?

Comment: It would also be useful to clarify how you want your "distinct" rule to work.  If two items have the same key but different values, should one be excluded; if two items have the same value but different keys, should one be excluded;  and in each case, if so, which item should be excluded?  Perhaps you could include examples of each of the three "distinct" cases in your example?

Comment: Why do you need to eliminate the two for loops?

Comment: @Daniel Renshaw: In merge rule 1 i mentioned that "First add the items which has a substring equals to any item in the list." so after that i need to add the rest of the elements(without duplicate key or value)

Comment: @ Daniel Renshaw: I need keep the first value(Key value pair) . the result should not contain same key or same value or same key-value pair.  The above code is working fine . I need to do this without using for loop

Comment: @ Zach : In case of thousands of key entries for loop is taking more time to execute

Comment: There are a lot of these dictionary/list merge questions popping up at the moment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it with LINQ and lambdas, as requested:

```
var keysFromList = new HashSet<string>(MyList);
var results =
    MyDict.Values
          .SelectMany(x => x)
          .OrderBy(x => {
                            int i = x.Key.LastIndexOf('_');
                            string k = (i < 0) ? x.Key.Trim() 
                                               : x.Key.Substring(0, i);
                            return keysFromList.Contains(k) ? 0 : 1;
                        })
          .Aggregate(new {
                             Results = new Dictionary<string, string>(),
                             Values = new HashSet<string>()
                         },
                     (a, x) => {
                                   if (!a.Results.ContainsKey(x.Key)
                                           && !a.Values.Contains(x.Value))
                                   {
                                       a.Results.Add(x.Key, x.Value);
                                       a.Values.Add(x.Value);
                                   }
                                   return a;
                               },
                     a => a.Results);
```

Comment: Nice solution :) Double the speed of my foreach, but most likely it won't matter since both are way faster than the original.

Comment: @Mikael: Really? I didn't benchmark but was expecting that your version would be faster, if anything, especially for larger sets of data. Yours looks like O(n) to me whereas using `OrderBy` would make mine roughly O(n log n). (I originally wrote something almost exactly the same as yours, then noticed that you'd already posted it so did the LINQ version instead!)

Comment: I meant, mine was quicker :) I can see now that I used the wrong words in that sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Loop wise this code is simpler, but not Linq:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> Test()
{
    int initcount = _myDict.Sum(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value.Count);

    var usedValues = new Dictionary<string, string>(initcount); //reverse val/key
    var result = new Dictionary<string, string>(initcount);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>> internalDicts in _myDict)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> valuePair in internalDicts.Value)
        {
            bool add = false;
            if (KeyInList(_myList, valuePair.Key))
            {
                string removeKey;
                if (usedValues.TryGetValue(valuePair.Value, out removeKey))
                {
                    if (KeyInList(_myList, removeKey)) continue;
                    result.Remove(removeKey);
                }
                usedValues.Remove(valuePair.Value);
                add = true;
            }
            if (!add && usedValues.ContainsKey(valuePair.Value)) continue;
            result[valuePair.Key] = valuePair.Value;
            usedValues[valuePair.Value] = valuePair.Key;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private static bool KeyInList(List<string> myList, string subKey)
{
    string key = subKey.Substring(0, subKey.LastIndexOf('_'));
    return myList.Contains(key);
}
```

Comment: @ Mikael Svenson : This method is fine. But its taking more time to execute. I'm having large volume of data to process. It taking around 12.45 seconds while the other is taking only 0.016 sec.

Comment: I'll fiddle with it some more and see if I can squeeze something else from my brain.

Comment: Just benchmarked on the small test data, and my version was about 5x faster than yours. Try to initialize the Dicts with expected number of items.

Comment: Edited my code to work with larger sets. Exchanged result.ContainsValue(...) with usedValues.ContainsKey(...). An obvious time save as ContainsValue is extremely slow O(n) compared to O(1) on ContainsKey.

Comment: If `_myList` could potentially contain many values then you *might* squeeze an extra bit of performance by populating a `HashSet<>` from it before you start looping: `HashSet<>.Contains` is O(1) whereas `List<>.Contains` is O(n).